# What is UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer in the context of my code

Tags: c, cs50

I was trying to complete crack from pset2 in cs50, and when I compiled my code it didn't throw any errors, but when I ran my code then it threw up some kind of error.

I have tried eliminating different parts of my code, and I found that after eliminating all the for loops the error stops showing up

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        printf("%s", crypt(argv[1], "hi"));
        string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", mess[1];
        int sl = strlen(letters);
        for (int x = 0; x < sl; x++)
        {
            mess[0][0] = letters[x];
            for (int y = 0; y < sl; y++)
            {
                mess[0][1] = letters[y];
                for (int z = 0; z < sl; z++)
                {
                    mess[0][2] = letters[z];
                    for (int a = 0; a < sl; a++)
                    {
                        mess[0][3] = letters[a];
                        for (int b = 0; b < sl; b++)
                        {
                            mess[0][4] = letters[b];
                            printf("%s", mess[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I expected to iterate over every possible combination of 5 letter combinations and output the string of those 5 letters. instead it gives back this:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==665==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000402a60 (pc 0x000000428037 bp 0x7ffd0ab11070 sp 0x7ffd0ab10e60 T665)
==665==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x428036 in main /root/sandbox/test.c:16:24
    #1 0x7f16d0022b96 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310
    #2 0x402a89 in _start (/root/sandbox/test+0x402a89)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==665==ABORTING
```

What I want to know is what this error means, why it happens, and how I can avoid it in the future

Answer (score 1):

In cs50 `string` is a typedef for `char *`. `mess[0]` is of type `char *` but was never initialized. You either need to allocate space with `malloc`

```
mess[0] = malloc(somesize * sizeof *mess[0]);
```

or you could use a `char` array:

```
char mess[1][somesize];
```

Also note that if you want to print `mess` with `printf("%s", mess[0]);` it has to be NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`string mess[1];`

`string` is from `cs50` typenamed as `char *` from [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h#L56).

So it is equal to:

`char *mess[1];`

Which is an uninitialized array of a one element. The elements type is a pointer to a character.

`mess[0][0] = ...`

This is taking on unintialized pointer `mess[0]` and dereferencing it and assigning it. `mess[0]` is uninitialized, so it's an invalid pointer, assigning to `mess[0][0]` is invalid - there is no valid memory there. There is no memory there to write to.

You can allocate the memory, ie.

`mess[0] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));`

ie. will allocate the memory for 256 characters (if successfull) and return a pointer to that memory region. The pointer is stored in the first member of the array `mess`. Then `mess[0]` will point to some region of memory, that is allocated just for your program, and is valid for 256 characters.